# Parallel Test Execution in Robot Framework |Selenium with Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, parallel-execution

how to achieve Parallel Test Execution in Robot Framework  which developed using  Selenium with java ?

Comment: Can you provide a more comprehensive description of what it is you want to do? Robot Framework is a Python application and it's SeleniumLibrary does not require any Java to run. So, please explain what it you you want to achieve and what the issues are you're running into.